# How to retrieve the array of object?

Tags: lightning-web-components

My Response:

```
0:{value:0, number:1},
1:{value:0, number:1},
2:{value:0, number:1}
```

Expected Output :

```
0:{number:1},
1:{number:1},
2:{number:1}
```

```
if(result){
    const value = JSON.parse(result)
    for(i=0; i<data.length ; i++){
        this.test= [..this.test, {value:data.value, number:data.number}];
    }
    
    get sample(){
        //how to iterate number alone
    }
```

I want to print all the number label . I'm new to lwc . How to iterate the label?

Comment: We'd need to see some code to help you.

Comment: I've added some codes to my question

Comment: Your response of what? Where do you expect this output. Your code snippet is too short to be helpful, is this a function? when is it called, what are the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use this:

```
value.forEach(element => {
console.log(element.number);
});
```

This should solution your problem

Comment: i have update the question with code . would you please help me

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: i tried 
data.map(element =>{
console.log(element.number);
}

i m returning the values

Comment: try, to iterate the value, value.forEach..

Comment: @MatheusCoelhoCampos Generally speaking, it's better to explain how something works than it is to just say "use this, it'll work". Code dumps usually don't help people build _understanding or knowledge_, and if you've make a mistake it's harder for other people to know what needs to be done to fix it (and tends to generate long, hard to read chains of comments).

Comment: Hi @DerekF, tks a lot for this help, I'm new in this.